# How to download quickstart VM 5.x for virtual box for windows 10?

Tags: virtualbox, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

How to download quickstart VM 5.x for virtual box for windows 10? I have installed oracle virtual box. But for cloudera qickstart VM I am not getting any source. I have searched a lot in google and youtube but the link or site all are referring is no more there. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to realize, is that a VM which can be run on any operating system by leveraging tools like VMware and Virtual Box.

Cloudera in fact no longer provides a quickstart VM for the legacy CDH 5 platform, this can be seen [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html) as you get redirected to CDP datacenter.

However be aware that CDH 5 relates to a **very** old distribution. I believe CDH 5 goes end of life this year. Even CDH 6 is not recommended for new clusters, as CDP 7 is already GA for a while. CDP, the [Cloudera Data Platform](https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-data-platform.html) is the successor to both CDH and HDP.

If you want to check out the latest version, there is a trial which should serve for most purposes that you may wanted to use the quickstart. This can be downloaded [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp/latest/release-guide/topics/cdpdc-trial-download-information.html).

---

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera, the company behind both CDH and CDP.